# Connect to certain timestamp for child version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, archiving

In ArcMap you can connect either to a historical marker or to a specified timespan by changing the version within the subtab Historic. I am however not quite sure on which parent-version this new version is based on. I suppose it is the DEFAULT-version because we need historic data that is only available through the archive-tables of our SDE.

Is it possible to connect to a specific timestamp for a child version?